# Pick groups that have at least one non-missing value in R

Tags: r, filter, grouping, extrapolation, longitudinal

I have a longitudinal data that I want to extrapolate one of its variables. I need to group the data by organizations' IDs and keep those groups/organizations that have at least one non-missing value for that variable (budget). It means that the organizations should be extrapolated individually, due to the longitudinal nature of data. I have used lots of different functions and codes but none of them worked. One of the simplest that I feel it should be working is the following:

```
DataX %>%
group_by(orgcode) %>%
filter(!is.na(budget) >= 1) %>%
mutate(budget=na.spline(budget))
```

The problem is that the filter only keeps the non-missing rows and does not take the grouping into account, so it cannot execute extrapolation. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be better if we had a reproducible example, but let's create a toy version of your data:

```r
DataX <- data.frame(orgcode = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 3),
                    budget  = c(NA, 21000, 22000,
                                30000, NA, 40000,
                                NA, NA, NA,
                                12000, 15000, 14000,
                                NA, NA, NA))

DataX
#>    orgcode budget
#> 1        A     NA
#> 2        A  21000
#> 3        A  22000
#> 4        B  30000
#> 5        B     NA
#> 6        B  40000
#> 7        C     NA
#> 8        C     NA
#> 9        C     NA
#> 10       D  12000
#> 11       D  15000
#> 12       D  14000
#> 13       E     NA
#> 14       E     NA
#> 15       E     NA
```

We can see that organizations with the `orgcode` C and E have all `NA` values and should be removed. We can do this by using a dummy variable to find out whether each group is `all(is.na(budget))` and filter on that:

```
library(dplyr)

DataX %>% 
  group_by(orgcode) %>% 
  mutate(allNA = !all(is.na(budget))) %>%
  filter(allNA) %>%
  select(-allNA)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 2
#> # Groups:   orgcode [3]
#>   orgcode budget
#>   <fct>    <dbl>
#> 1 A           NA
#> 2 A        21000
#> 3 A        22000
#> 4 B        30000
#> 5 B           NA
#> 6 B        40000
#> 7 D        12000
#> 8 D        15000
#> 9 D        14000
```

<sup>Created on 2020-07-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It's my first time asking a question here! I will definitely create a toy version of my data next time. Thank you so much for doing this! Your code worked!

Comment: Oh wait! I just noticed that the code is running with no problem but all the missing values are still there:/

Comment: @MarjanDavoodi do you mean the orgcodes that are all NA are still there, or that the orgcodes with some missing values still have NA?

Comment: The organizations with some missing values still have NAs.

Comment: My bad! I forgot to add the extrapolation line! Sorry about that. I'm all set!